# make jetty:run auto load dependences during running

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a maven project which own the following structure:

```
api(with packaging pom)
  pom.xml
  api-common(with packaging jar)
    pom.xml
  api-webapp(with packaging war)
    pom.xml
```

The `api` is the parent of `api-common` and `api-webapp`.

`api-webapp` have a dependency of `api-common`.

Now when I run `mvn jetty:run` inside the `api/api-webapp`,jetty can not auto load the change of the module `api-common`.

Any idea?

BTW,I use maven3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `api-webapp` depends on `api-common` and they are separate projects, `api-webapp` will look for it's dependencies in the maven repository: your `.m2` directory, then the remote repo.  You'll need to compile and install your changes in `api-common` first before `api-webapp` can see them.

`api-webapp` has no knowledge of the location of the source of `api-common` so it can not detect changes.  The fact that they share a common parent does not give them the ability to see each other.

That's the general maven answer, but the jetty plugin does provide a workaround to this issue by letting you provide additional classpath for the container.  See [this defect](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1206)

Comment: I know the mechanisms,so I run `mvn install` after I modify the codes,then I run `mvn jetty:run`. However I wonder how do people do the web application in this case?